# Using canopy behind NTLM ploxy

Tags: python, machine-learning, proxy, enthought, canopy

I am trying to use Canopy in my job (just a free version before choosing a python ML tool), but I cannot connect or download packages via package manager,  probably because of NTLM proxy.

I use linux ubuntu 16 and cntlm, and the only way I got is downloading each egg manually, then installing it via command line (help of [@jonathan-march](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1988991/jonathan-march)). This is simple, until the number of packages increases.

I have already read [this old post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21404565/connection-behind-proxy), [this other solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24881718/https-request-via-urllib2-fails-behind-ntlm-proxy/24951038#24951038) and the [official site help](https://support.enthought.com/hc/en-us/articles/204469150-Using-Canopy-Behind-a-Proxy-Firewall), but maybe any of you knows any hack for that.

Thanks in advance.

ps.: This is the full help I got from Jonathan

---

You can take one of the following approaches:

For a small installation - treat your Canopy installation as disconnected / isolated, and update it manually, as discussed in [this article](https://support.enthought.com/hc/en-us/articles/204469130-Updating-Canopy-packages-and-application-on-a-disconnected-machine).

For a large installation - treat your Canopy installation as disconnected / isolated, and bring the package server inside your firewall, using the [Enthought Deployment Server](https://www.enthought.com/products/enthought-deployment-server/) (separate product).

Set up an intermediate standard proxy, which Canopy can talk to, and which can talk to your NTLM proxy. This process is discussed in this comment on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24951038/1988991), which recommends using the [ntlmmaps Authorization Proxy Server software](http://ntlmaps.sourceforge.net/). We do not routinely support this scenario, but would be glad to help you set it up, under a support services contract, for example as part of a multi-seat licensing agreement.

---

At this point, I don't want to make big changes in my infrastructure, but I need to give my managers another alternative.

Comment: Edited to include the original links to the articles / pages cited in my comments.